# more then one value returns in a list based on enum search

Tags: c#, linq

I am returning a list of data and searching through them based on enum. Each enum has each value, but I keep getting more than one result repeatedly. Can you please advise what am I doing wrong. Each item has its own enum. SO I have three enums in collection I should get three items, however I get all several times duplicated

```cs
private ObservableCollection<TextFormField> _results = new  ObservableCollection<TextFormField>();
private ObservableCollection<TextFormField> _allResults = new  ObservableCollection<TextFormField>();
public List<EnumClass> Fieldtype { get; set; }

var list = _allResults.GroupBy(i => i.FieldType).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
            
foreach (var s in _includeFields.Fieldtype - ENUM)
{
    var test = list.Where(a => a.FieldType == s);
    foreach(var i in test)
    {
        var item = new TextFormField
        {
            Text = textField.Text,
            Description = textField.Description,
        };
    }
}
                                            
Results.Add(item);
```

Expected output
Text
text

outcome
Text
text
Text
text
Text
text

Comment: this is a basic C#/LINQ question.  It has nothing to do with Xamarin Forms.

Comment: What are `_allResults`, `_includeFields` and `Results`? It would be helpful if you described what types are those objects..

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question and add some sample input and expected output. It's unclear which part of the code is not behaving like you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

```cs
// all results found
ObservableCollection<Item>() _allResults = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
// wanted field types
var _includedFieldTypes = new List<FieldTypeEnum>();
// results to display
ObservableCollection<Item>() Results = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

// get one item for each included field type
var results = _allResults
    // only filter fields with included field type
    .Where(a => _includedFieldTypes.Contains(a.FieldType))
    // group by field type
    .GroupBy(i => i.FieldType)
    // take first item from each group
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();

// add results to observable collection
foreach(var result in results){
    Results.Add(result);
}
```